# What is the difference between $\longmapsto$ and $\mapsto$? (I am aware of \to and $\mapsto$, but $\longmapsto$ is new to me)

Tags: notation

Is $\longmapsto$ just another notation for $\to$ ?

(I am aware of $\to$ and $\mapsto$, but $\longmapsto$ is new to me)

Comment: For function/mapping, I think are the same.

Comment: Sometimes the longer arrow looks better, sometimes the shorter one.

Comment: It allows you to write $\overset{f}{\longmapsto}$; compare it to $\overset{f}{\mapsto}$.